# Between no devuelve ultima fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un campo fecha DateTime en mi tabla MySql y estoy empleando la siguiente consulta para obtener los valores entre dos fechas, pero por ejemplo si ingreso 01/04/2021 fecha inicial y 01/29/2021 me devuelve todos los registros desde 01/04/2021 hasta 01/28/2021 fecha final, me esta dejando fuera el 01/29.

Otra cosa estoy haciendo uso correcto dedel Having? ya que quiero hacer la suma de Duration y ProducedParts siempre y cuando el campo State sea igual a 10 y 11 dentro de las fechas dadas.

Esta es la consulta,

```
    SELECT  ld.No ,

ld.LSet,

SUM(ld.Duration) as TotalDuration ,

SUM(ld.ProducedParts) as TotalPcs,

ld.State,

 DATE_FORMAT (ld.InsertTime ,  '%d-%m-%Y') as DateIni,

b.WireA ,

b.WireLengthA  ,

b.WireB ,

b.WireLengthB  ,

b.Terminal1,

b.Seal1,

b.Terminal2,

b.Seal2,

b.Terminal3,

b.Seal3,

b.Terminal4,

b.Seal4

FROM ldata ld

INNER JOIN bomv b

ON ld.Lset = b.Lset

WHERE

ld.InsertTime between STR_TO_DATE('@{1}', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')--Aqui el Where con Between

AND

STR_TO_DATE('@{2}', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')

GROUP BY

ld.No ,

ld.Lset,

ld.State,

b.WireA ,

b.WireLengthA  ,

b.WireB ,

b.WireLengthB  ,

b.Terminal1,

b.Seal1,

b.Terminal2,

b.Seal2,

b.Terminal3,

b.Seal3,

b.Terminal4,

b.Seal4

HAVING ld.State = 10

OR

ld.State = 11

ORDER BY ld.InsertTime, ld.No
```

Espero puedan ayudarme que es lo que estoy haciendo mal en la consulta.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Puedes probar formateando la fecha de esta manera ld.InsertTime between STR_TO_DATE('@{1}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('@{2}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

Answer (score 0):

Creería que no está trayendo las fechas '01/29/2021' debido a que la columna InsertTime es de tipo TIMESTAMP, y en la fecha_final no estás teniendo en cuenta las horas, minutos y segundos (por lo tanto no está incluyendo ese día).

Ej: si InsertTime es '01/29/2021 15:05:03' y vos haces `InsertTime Between '01/04/2021' AND '01/29/2021'`, no traerá dicha fecha debido a que las 15 hs del dia 29 son superiores a la fecha final (del between) que llega al primer segundo del día 29.

Tienes dos opciones para arreglar esto:

1. Castear InsertTime a tipo fecha y usar between como lo estabas haciendo (sin tener en cuenta horas, minutos y segundos):

`WHERE DATE(ld.InsertTime) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('@{1}', '%c/%e/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('@{2}', '%c/%e/%Y')`

2. Pasar la fecha_inicial igual a '01/04/2021 0:0:0' y la fecha_final como '01/29/2021 23:59:59' (o sea que incluya todo el día final, si no especificas las horas, minutos y segundos no va a incluir el día final).

Con respecto al **HAVING**:

Si vos querés traer solo los registros con state 10 y  11, entonces lo tenés que hacer en el WHERE, no en HAVING:

`WHERE ld.State = 10 OR ld.State = 11`

HAVING se usa para restringir utilizando funciones agragas. Ej: si quisieras retornar solo aquellas filas donde la duración total sea mayor a 1000 utilizarías HAVING `HAVING SUM(ld.Duration) > 1000`.